# Is it possible to change IIS settings from web config

Tags: asp.net, iis, hosting, web-config

I'm using url rewriting.net. I'm testing web on the local host, it is successfully work. But When i deploying web to remote host, url rewriting not work. Problem is (The resource cannot be found). I found problem. My deployed remote host IIS configuration is (Virtual dir->Properties->Home directory->Application Mapping->.aspx->Edit->"Check that file exist"  is checked). I need to uncheck them. But my deployed host control panel not have a application mapping function.

How to uncheck this option using web.config?

Is it possible?

Has you another idea?

Comment: Is this on IIS6 or IIS7?

Comment: I don't know. maybe IIS7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IIS6**

If this is IIS6 then unfortunately there is no way to change the script map settings via  your ASP.NET `web.config` file.

You would need to find a hoster that permitted this configuration change via their control panel, or ask your present hoster (nicely) to change this for you.

**IIS7**

If this is IIS7 then you need to add (if it doesn't already exist) a `<system.webServer />` configuration section to your `web.config` file and modify the handler behaviour:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
       <handlers>
            <!-- remove existing handlers -->
            <remove name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0" />
            <remove name="PageHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
            <!-- add back but set resourceType="Unspecified" to prevent
                 checking if file exists -->
            <add name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0" 
                resourceType="Unspecified" 
                path="*.aspx" 
                verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" 
                modules="IsapiModule" 
                scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" 
                requireAccess="Script" 
                preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" 
                responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="PageHandlerFactory-Integrated"
                resourceType="Unspecified"
                path="*.aspx" 
                verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" 
                type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" 
                preCondition="integratedMode" />
       </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This will only work if your hoster has delegated read/write access to the Handler Mappings feature.

I'd be fairly surprised though if this was IIS 7 and the `PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0` and `PageHandlerFactory-Integrated` handler were configured as `resourceType="File"` or `resourceType="Either"`. Out of the box they're configured not to check for the existence of files and folders.

Comment: If host is IIS7, how can configure?